# Java API for KML in play framework

Tags: playframework, kml, google-earth, playframework-1.x

I am trying to generate kml file in play framework (1.2.4 )using library "[Java API for KML](http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/)".

But i am not able to import the library.

i just added jar file to pat /lib and below line to dependencies.yml

```
require:
    // other jars
- de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml -> JavaAPIforKml-sources
```

Is there any good documentation or what is the best way for generating [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) files in play framework.

Comment: You need to always give proper version, I deleted my answer as it doesn't fit Play 1.x at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at  http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/FAQ#FAQ-NoClassDefFoundError%3F

the dependency should be

```
- de.micromata.jak -> JavaAPIforKml 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

and you should also define the repository (see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/dependency#repositories)

so you depedencies.yml will be:

```
require:
    - play
    - de.micromata.jak -> JavaAPIforKml 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT


repositories:

     - javadev:
        type: iBiblio
        root: "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        contains:
           - de.micromata.jak -> *
```

*only tested in play 1.2.5*